# Additional Spark' installation's access to HDFS and Hive

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.5.0 installed and it has Spark v1.5.0 bundled. When I launch `spark-shell`

```
scala> val data = sc.textFile("/hdfs/path/file.csv")
```

Spark was able to read from HDFS (proven by using `data.first`), even without the `hdfs://namenode:port/` URL.
Because I have a use-case for older version of Spark, namely, v1.4.0. I installed / untar an older version to HOME dir.

When I try to do the same thing, the sc.textFile points to the Linux local file system instead of HDFS. How can I make additional Spark's installation point to HDFS, even without specifying `hdfs://namenode:port/` URL?

The second thing is, to access Hive tables, I copy the hive-site.xml to Spark's conf dir. After doing that in Spark default installation, I can easily query Hive tables:

```
scala> val orders = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM default.orders")

scala> orders.limit(5).foreach(println)
```

and this will display the rows.

When I try to do the same thing on Spark v1.4, I get errors. How can I access Hive tables the same way as default installation do?

Comment: add hadoop conf directory in spark classpath. sc.textFile behaviour is same in soark-1.5 and spark-1.4

Comment: @shekhar Does copying the spark-env.sh to conf of the original Spark (v1.5) to additional Spark (v1.4) will do?

Comment: check value of HADOOP_CONF_DIR in spark-env.sh, it should point to your hadoop/conf directory